# Do potions fall faster than players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had an idea to prolong the player’s lifetime in the void by having a dispenser throw regeneration potions down, but I soon realized that this would only work if they fell faster than the player (if not, then slow falling would also be needed). So do potions fall faster than players and by how much are they faster/slower?

Comment: Even if they fell faster than players, if they were in the void they would get destroyed anyway.

Comment: You would need instant health 2 at least, the void damage gets increased depending on how far down the player is. If you have a dispenser set up, I would assume this isn't in case you fell in the void but are trying to survive, in that case this video might be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LB1snmO1SB0

Answer (score 1):

I don't think potions fall faster, but you could place a dispenser above you and begin dropping potions from it, then jump down into the void. You should be able to survive the void, but make sure you have plenty of potions in the dispenser so you don't run out.